# Prevent setShowWhenLocked activity from showing over lockscreen automatically

Tags: android

I have an activity that can be triggered by an intent, and I want this to work on the lockscreen, so I have called `setShowWhenLocked(true)`.

However, now I have the issue that if I have the activity opened, then lock the screen, when I wake the phone, the activity is still open rather than the default lockscreen. Likewise, if the activity is already open while the phone is locked, pressing the power button twice (turn off then on) the screen does not bring me back to the lockscreen.

I have tried to call `setShowWhenLocked(true)` in `onNewIntent()` rather than `onCreate()` in hopes that I can detect that the app was triggered by intent, and only then allow the app to show over the lockscreen. Then call `setShowWhenLocked(false)` in `onPause()` to hide the app when the screen is locked. However, it seems calling `setShowWhenLocked(true)` in `onNewIntent()` is too late, and the system has already decided to not show the app over the lockscreen.